# Delete multiple rows with specific parameters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

I wanted to know if is there any solutions to delete multiple rows in one query?

I'm using a select element with multiple input so I have an array in my $_POST when I'm sending my form.

For example, I want to unsubscribe an users from one table to more than one lesson So I have:

```
users.id | lesson.id
--------------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
1        | 4
```

My select post me an array with the lesson.id:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

How can I with only one query, delete all rows from my table ?

BTW, I know the users.id all the time.

Comment: Please show your select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete just these three `lesson_id`s

```
delete from lesson_table
where users_id = 1 and lesson_id in (2, 3, 4)
```

If you want to delete all but one arbitrary lesson and you know, user 1 has 4 lessons, then you can `limit` the delete to 3 lesson_ids

```
delete from lesson_table
where users_id = 1
limit 3
```